# From what number the following conversion integer -> double -> integer is not valid?

Tags: c++, integer, double, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Assuming that my computer use IEEE 754 floating-point encoding, I wonder what is the smallest number for which the following function return false:

```
constexpr bool test(const unsigned long long int x)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned long long int>(static_cast<double>(x)) == x;
}
```

Comment: 2**53 + 1, I reckon. Put another way 0x20000000000001

Comment: Oops, the question was for "==" and not "!="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mantissa on a `double` in IEEE-754 is 53 bits (52 bits and one hidden, being very technical). That means that if the highest bits in `x` are above bit 52, and some of the lower bits are non-zero, the compare will fail.

You could find this out by writing a piece of code:

```
unsigned long long x = 0x1;

while(x > 0)
{
   x <<= 1ULL;
   if (!test(x+1))
   {
      cout << "x=" << hex << x << endl;
      break;

   }
}
```

Edit: fixed up code a little bit after actually testing it.

It does print `x=20000000000000` as predicted.

Or, if you want to use `<limits>`, you can achieve the same result with:

```
numeric_limits<double> n;
cout << "digits=" << dec << n.digits << " -> " << hex << (1ULL << n.digits) << endl;
```

Comment: Is it possible to compute this number at compile-time using std::numeric_limits ?

Comment: Probably. Let me get back to you after I've experimented a little bit - I don't know off the top of my head exactly which one of the fields does that, but I think it can be done.